# bigquery execute immediate to call procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I need to call procedure dynamically with dataset and procedure name

```
execute immediate "CALL `" || "project_name" || "." || "db_name" || ".procedure`()";
```

But it throws error

> SQL created by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE contains unsupported statement type:
> CallStatement

How can I call procedure with execute command

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#call) statement part of your scripting.
You don't need to wrap the CALL statement in execute immediate.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "select 1";
CALL myDataset.UpdateSomeTables('someAccountId', retCode);
```

Comment: dataset name is dynamic

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam you need to use an if/then statements and write all the dataset names in clear, you cannot use dynamic variable for a dataset as a prefix for a procedure.

Comment: the dataset is being generated dynamically so cannot predict its name beforehand to put the if conditions

Comment: you cannot solve this in scripting then, you need to use some other way like Cloud Workflows steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a procedure dynamically with
`execute immediate format("""call %.%.%""", project_id, dataset, procedure_name)`

For a very special usecase I have once had to create a procedure that would dynamic call other procedures.
You can make a procedure like:

```
create or replace call_procedure_procedure(project_id STRING, dataset STRING, procedure_name STRING)
begin
   execute immediate format("""call %.%.%""", project_id, dataset, procedure_name)
end
```

then you call your new procedure with:

`call call_procedure_procedure(project_id, dataset, procedure_name)`

Comment: Hi, for me that does not work on google BigQuery. The format function itself cannot we used like that. One has to format like %s for string. Even after fixing the format the error message remains: SQL created by EXECUTE IMMEDIATE contains unsupported statement type: CallStatement

Answer (score 0):

The only way workaround I could come up with was to use the routine definition stored in INFORMATION SCHEMA.ROUTINES to recreate the stored proc you are trying to call dynamically within the stored proc you are running, call that directly newly created stored proc directly, then drop it after.  Code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE [*dataset*].*call_dynamic_procedure*(project_name STRING, db_name STRING, procedure STRING)

BEGIN

    DECLARE sp_ddl_lookup STRING;
    DECLARE sp_ddl STRING;
    DECLARE sp_temp STRING;

    SET sp_ddl_lookup = CONCAT(FORMAT('select routine_definition from %s.%s.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where specific_name = ',project_name,db_name),FORMAT('\'%s\'',procedure));

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sp_ddl_lookup INTO sp_ddl;

    SET sp_temp = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE [*dataset*].temp_procedure() ',sp_temp,';');

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sp_temp;

    CALL [*dataset*].temp_procedure();

    DROP PROCEDURE [*dataset*].temp_procedure();

END
```